# change cell color in easyui datagrid

Tags: jquery, datagrid, background-color

Hellow, i want to change cell color based on condition , if any cell with null value in database then the background color is changed.

in easyui tutorial, we can change the background color row. like this :

```
 $('#tt').datagrid({
    rowStyler:function(index,row){
    if (row.listprice>50){
    return 'background-color:pink;color:blue;font-weight:bold;';
    }
    }
    });
```

but how to change color in cell?

Answer (score 1):

```
<th field="listprice" formatter="formatListprice">listprice</th>

function formatListprice(val,row){
    if (val > 50){
        return '<span style="background-color:pink;color:blue;font-weight:bold;">'+val+'</span>';
    } else {
        return val;
    }
}
```